# SQL to LINQ with many joins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I'm struggling with a conversion of SQL query to LINQ.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT dbo.ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATION_ID, 
       dbo.ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
             dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY.DIRECTORY_IDENTIFIER, 
             dbo.DETAIL_REQUIREMENT.DETAIL_ID, 
       dbo.DETAIL_REQUIREMENT.DETAIL_IDENTIFIER, 
             dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.DIRECTORY_ATTRIBUTE, 
             dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.ATTRIBUTE_VALIDATION, 
       dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.ATTRIBUTE_TRANSFORMATION, 
             dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.DETAIL_ACCESS

FROM  dbo.ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN
      dbo.DETAIL_REQUIREMENT ON dbo.ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATION_ID = dbo.DETAIL_REQUIREMENT.ORGANIZATION_ID INNER JOIN
      dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY INNER JOIN
      dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING ON dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY.ORGANIZATION_ID = dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.ORGANIZATION_ID AND 
      dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY.DIRECTORY_TYPE_ID = dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.DIRECTORY_TYPE_ID AND 
      dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY.DIRECTORY_ID = dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.DIRECTORY_ID ON 
      dbo.DETAIL_REQUIREMENT.DETAIL_ID = dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.DETAIL_ID AND 
      dbo.ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATION_ID = dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY_MAPPING.ORGANIZATION_ID

WHERE dbo.ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATION_ID = 0 AND 
      dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY.DIRECTORY_ID = 1 AND 
            dbo.PWR_ORGANIZATION_DIRECTORY.DIRECTORY_TYPE_ID = 1
```

And this is how I started but got confused when there were two and three joins between tables:

```
var megaFetch = from org in context.Organizations
            join detReq in context.DetailRequirements on org.OrganizationId equals detReq.OrganizationId
            join detMap in context.OrganizationDirectoryMappings on org.OrganizationId equals detMap.OrganizationId &&
```

Can someone guide me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to join a tables in more than one column, create anonymous types with both sides having same number of fields. It should be like;

```
new {col1 = x.col1, col2 = x.col2, ...} equals new { col1 = y.col1, col2 = y.col2, ...}
```